# What can you achieve in 100 days on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

100 days ago I asked myself this question and wondered how cool is the Magento Community ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After 100 days on Magento StackExchange, I can say one thing:

> Magento community is awesome!!

In 100 days, here's what I achieved:

- I got up to 6633 reputation
- 49 badges earned
- 15 questions asked
- 285 answers
- 373 votes cast
- 41% accepted answer percentage rate

You can find the whole experience here if you feel like reading: http://www.digital-pianism.com/en/blog/100-days-on-magento-stackexchange/

Comment: This is Just amazing, very difficult to believe that someone achieved so much in just 100 days.... and even this community & Magento beginners like me need lot from guys like you. i hope you will achieve double than this in next 100 days &  totally its  pleasure to see your answers  & you are a star. Keep it up :-)

Comment: Well played! I've only been a member for 3 months and 320 reputation has taken quite a bit of effort so I can only guess how much you've put in to helping the community. Thank you :D

Comment: greats achieve  Raphael :) keep it  up

Comment: @AmitBera its feast for eyes to see a star is praising other star , i saw you were helping others in mse at mid night & even at early morning 5 a.m . great job :-)

Comment: Please update the question & answer with next 100 days status, you done amazing job in last 100 days....

Comment: @BabyinMagento haha yeah I should do that. I'll probably do a 365 days recap instead

Comment: if you wait until 365 days, than there will be no space in stackoverflow database to save your reputation points :-)